# How to use persistent in a monad stack?

Tags: haskell, persistent

I have been enjoying learning Haskell and I think I am making some good progress with the help of folks here and at #haskell. My learning is mostly still at the point where I look at examples and try to abstract out the techniques applied there and apply them to my own code.

Currently, I have started looking at developing monad stacks for various applications and I am looking to incorporate the functionality of the persistent framework into my application.

Here is my monad stack:

```
newtype App a = App { unApp :: StateT AppState (SqlPersistT (ResourceT (LoggingT IO))) a }
                deriving ( Applicative
                         , Functor
                         , Monad
                         , MonadIO
                         , MonadState AppState
                         )
```

`AppState` is just a record data type holding a single Int value in this example.

My main function looks like:

```
main = runApp "./test.sqlite" (AppState 69) runMigrate
```

where `runApp` is supposed to unwrap all the monads:

```
runApp :: Text -> AppState -> App a -> IO a
runApp t s a = 
  runStdoutLoggingT . runResourceT . withSqliteConn t . runSqlConn . flip evalStateT s . unApp
```

and `runMigrate` is the application to run in the `App` monad. In this case I was shooting for just getting it to run the migration:

```
runMigrate :: App ()
runMigrate = return $ liftPersist $ runMigration migrateAll
```

The compiler points out that I don't know what I am doing with the complaint:

```
Main.lhs:59:16:
    Couldn't match type ‘m0 ()’ with ‘()’
    Expected type: App ()
      Actual type: App (m0 ())
    In the expression: return $ liftPersist $ runMigration migrateAll
    In an equation for ‘runMigrate’:
        runMigrate = return $ liftPersist $ runMigration migrateAll
```

Questions:

1. What is the right way to do this?
2. What happens if in my monad stack I introduce a `ReaderT`? Given that `SqlPersistT` is really a `ReaderT` how can I make sure that `ask` is matched to the real `ReaderT` and not `SqlPersistT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question: `return` isn't the right function --- the point of `return` is that `return x` does none of the work of your monad and just returns a value.  I think you probably want:

```
runMigrate = App $ lift $ runMigration migrateAll
```

`App` lifts your `newtype` definition into your monad; `lift` lifts the `PersistT` into the wrapping `StateT`.

(Incidentally, I recommend naming `App . lift . runMigration` as something like `runMigrationApp` if you're going to be using it a lot.)